# How to call api with controller's method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1

I want to call an ASP.NET Core 2.1.0 Web API with a controller's method.

I tried following but I get an error

> Cannot GET /api/remote/NewAc/test1

Code:

```
[Route("api/remote/{action}")]
//[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class RemoteController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly MyContext _context;

    public RemoteValsController(MyContext context)
    { _context = context; }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<OkObjectResult> NewAc()
    {
        var r = await _context.TypeOfAccounts.AnyAsync();
        return Ok(new { r = true });
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<OkObjectResult> NewAc([FromRoute] string AccountType)
    {
        var r = await _context.TypeOfAccounts.AnyAsync(o => o.AccountType.ToUpper() == AccountType.ToUpper());
        return Ok(new { r = !r });
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

I tried both `[HttpPost]` and `[HttpGet]` but in vain.

Comment: Could you double check this code sample? The constructor is wrong and therefore we could assume this isn't really the code that is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-check the defined routes for the controller.

```
[Route("api/remote/[action]")] //<-- NOTE Token replacement in route templates
[ApiController]
public class RemoteController : ControllerBase {
    private readonly MyContext _context;

    public RemoteController(MyContext context) { 
        _context = context; 
    }

    //GET api/remote/NewAc
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> NewAc() {
        var r = await _context.TypeOfAccounts.AnyAsync();
        return Ok(new { r = true });
    }

    //GET api/remote/NewAc/test1
    [HttpGet("{accountType}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> NewAc(string accountType) {
        var r = await _context.TypeOfAccounts.AnyAsync(o => o.AccountType.ToUpper() == accountType.ToUpper());
        return Ok(new { r = !r });
    }
}
```

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Answer (score 0):

First, mapped routes and attribute routing are an either/or affair. If you have route attributes involved, the route definition in your Startup is not applicable at all.

Second, you can't just throw `[FromRoute]` in front a param and magically have it in the route. In fact, that attribute isn't necessary at all unless there's some ambiguity about where the param value is actually supposed to come from. If you want it from the route, then it needs to be part of your route template. Simply:

```
[HttpGet("{id}/{AccountType}")]
public async Task<OkObjectResult> NewAc(string AccountType)
{
    var r = await _context.TypeOfAccounts.AnyAsync(o => o.AccountType.ToUpper() == AccountType.ToUpper());
    return Ok(new { r = !r });
}
```